# How can i use build ipa with cordova cli?

Tags: ios, cordova

Now i have someone's .p12 certificate and .mobileprovision and i have a cordova ios 
project, so i want use cordova cli: cordova build ios --device --release to build signed ipa, what can i do?

when i try cordova build ios --device --release --buildConfig it show :

 `No iOS profile matching 'TeamID/UUID' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching 'TeamID/UUID'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor`

> i installed the profile with double click it already and load the .p12 to keychain too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when i use cordova with version 5.4.1 and xode 7.0 it works.

Comment: I found that with cordova latest version 8.0.0 and xcode 7.0 it still works well